# Creating a page for every product in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm designing a website for shopping.

When I click a product from the products page, I want to get a page only containing information about that one product but do I have to create a new page separately for every product on the products page?

I only know some javascript and jquery. I don't know PHP.

Comment: You can parse JSON data from file...

Comment: Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more guidance on the kind of topics SO can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to create separate page or each products if it is static. If you want to use php then you can put all the products in mysql table and fetch from the database and get the product by id. Since you dont know PHP you can also do in javascript like storing the products in json format and get them via id using single page for example product detail. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

No,you don't have create page for each product.You just need to create a template where in you will be grabing the corresponding product information.Based on the product and its belonging category ,you have to generate a route with id.The data should be JSON format for better accessibility.

Comment: I have a question, it would be great if you can help me. I have a php template in which I have dynamic meta tags like `title` and `description`. I know that title and description are important metas for searching engines. So my question is how would this search engine behave when positioning a dynamic template like mine? Where can I find some info about it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only have experience working with static pages. Which is to be expected as you've said you are a beginner. I suggest adding PHP to your question tags and getting some help on that.

With PHP or other server side technologies you can generate **dynamic** page content compared to static. You would make the markup as a template, then on the server your code would generate what goes inside the mark-up and the page will be served.

If you are using web hosting that has PHP support, try changing your page extension to .php and adding:

```
<?php echo date(DATE_RFC2822); ?>
```

By refreshing the page you will see the output will change as the time changes.

By using server side scripting you could put all your product information in a CSV (comma seperetaed values file) and retrieve your product listings from the CSV files with their individual links etc.

The PHP documentation is a great place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

PHP is not the only server-side scripting technology, in fact as you've started learning JavaScript you could even look into to alternatives like NodeJS etc. You are at the point where you now must start working with dynamic content which everyone gets to at some point of learning front-end technology.

Comment: Sad someone has down-voted all answers with no feedback simply for trying to give OP information he needs regardless of the poor direction his question takes.